# Set enum or #define tag to an object in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

When you build a lot of equal object is a good design partner set a tag to identifier, so:

```
UITextField *object1, *object2;
//Initialize it
[object1 setDelegate:self];
[object2 setDelegate:self];
[object1 setTag: 1]; 
[object2 setTag: 2];
```

To be more easy and "beautiful" understand the code, you can create a enum.

```
typedef enum {
      MyTextField1 = 1,
      MyTextField2
} allTextField;
```

So, you will not put just a number and can set tag in this way:

```
[object1 setTag: MyTextField1];
[object2 setTag: MyTextField2];
```

Than in any delegate function you can treat it more easy

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
   switch(textField.tag) {
       case MyTextField1: return YES;
       case MyTextField2: return NO;
   }
}
```

But, when you will build in `Interface Builder` in XCode, you can set the tag in this field:

[image]

But if I set it, I will receive:

[image]

There is no way to set the tag anything than a number in Interface Builder?

Comment: An enum is an integer, and the tag field expects to be filled with an integer, so you cannot use your enum's name in that field.

Comment: I can even make `#define MyTextField1 1` So this is a int to. But not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use an enum in IB. Because IB files are serialized objects. And when they get loaded at run time, they can't make the reference to the name of the enum.

Comment: No other idea? I know I can set it in code when the .nit is loaded. But in interface builder you will not know this.

Comment: There is no way. In interface builder the text field does not allow entering anything else than an integer value. Even if you could, it wouldn't work. Nib's don't work this way.

Answer (score 1):

### Define vs Enum

`#define`'s can be easier to type because you don't need the `=` or have to worry about the trailing `,` between each element. But you do have the extra `#define` which is less DRY. I use enums, but either way is fine.

```
typedef enum {
      SongNameLabelTag = 1,
      PlayButtonTag = 2
} MyViewControllerTags;
```

vs.

```
#define SongNameLabelTag 1
#define PlayButtonTag 2
```

### Naming Convention

I name tags in format: `<name><short type description>Tag`

e.g. `SongNameLabelTag`, `PlayButtonTag`

### Tag values in IB

*The goal here is to avoid giving an element the same tag.*

I find it frustrating to remember the last tag I used when working in IB.

Keeping your defines up to date seems like a solution but this is annoying and there are some times when it won't work.

E.g. Moving an element to another view controller. (I usually extract groups of elements to separate view controllers. This will lead to your numbering starting at weird numbers or clashing with existing elements.)

When prototyping and working quickly it slows me down to have to add each element tag as a `#define`. I like to work as quickly as possible :)

---

My solution is to **use random numbers**. The max you can use is `NSIntegerMax (32-bit)` which is 2147483647.

Most importantly they need to be quickly available!

Just bookmark this link every time you need some random tags:

http://www.random.org/integers/?num=100&min=1&max=999999999&col=1&base=10&format=html&rnd=new

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, and it is a shame because technically it could be implemented. Specially with all that syntax analyzer.

So far that is the only reason for which I manually code some menus and avoid the interface builder.